# codepro analytix - listing all current rules across rule sets

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rad, codepro

I need to analyse the rules in my codePro installation. It has a few custom rulesets over the default ones as well which might have redundant instances. I would require to list all rules, their descriptions and rulesets.

I am aware of the export rule feature but that does not cut it for over 50 or so rules or the descriptions. Could you help with a smarter solution than browsing through each rule and adding to the report?

Thanks